# Add response headers via RequestHook

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

How do I add headers to the response in Testcafe? So far I've tried using the `onResponse` function of the `RequestHook` class. Using a `RequestLogger`, I can validate that the headers were added, but they don't actually make it to the browser (not visible in the list of response headers in Chrome's network tab).

Here's what I'm using:

```js
import { RequestLogger, RequestHook } from 'testcafe';

class HeadersHook extends RequestHook {
  constructor(requestFilterRules) {
    super(requestFilterRules, { includeBody: false, includeHeaders: true });
  }

  async onRequest(event) { }

  async onResponse(event) {
    event.headers['bar'] = 'foo';
    event.headers.foo = 'bar';
    console.log('hook: ', event.headers);
  }
}

fixture('My Fixture');

test('Example internal-sdk usage', async (t) => {
  const headerLogger = RequestLogger(process.env.TEST_URL, {
    logResponseHeaders: true
  });

  // This order is significant: adding the logger first causes it to miss the additional headers.
  // Not sure why.
  await t.addRequestHooks(new HeadersHook(process.env.TEST_URL));
  await t.addRequestHooks(headerLogger);

  await t.navigateTo(process.env.TEST_URL);
  console.log('logger: ', headerLogger.requests.length, headerLogger.requests[0].response.headers);

  t.debug();
});
```

This gives the following console output which seems to indicate that the headers were successfully added:

```
hook:  {
  'content-type': 'text/html;charset=utf-8',
  vary: 'origin,accept-encoding',
  'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
  'access-control-expose-headers': 'WWW-Authenticate,Server-Authorization',
  'cache-control': 'no-cache',
  'content-encoding': 'gzip',
  date: 'Fri, 05 Mar 2021 16:43:06 GMT',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'keep-alive': 'timeout=5',
  'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
  bar: 'foo',
  foo: 'bar'
}
logger:  1 {
  'content-type': 'text/html;charset=utf-8',
  vary: 'origin,accept-encoding',
  'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
  'access-control-expose-headers': 'WWW-Authenticate,Server-Authorization',
  'cache-control': 'no-cache',
  'content-encoding': 'gzip',
  date: 'Fri, 05 Mar 2021 16:43:06 GMT',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'keep-alive': 'timeout=5',
  'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
  bar: 'foo',
  foo: 'bar'
}
```

But in the browser network tab, all I see is this (additional headers missing):

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-expose-headers: WWW-Authenticate,Server-Authorization
cache-control: no-cache
connection: keep-alive
content-encoding: gzip
content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8
date: Fri, 05 Mar 2021 16:45:51 GMT
keep-alive: timeout=5
transfer-encoding: chunked
vary: origin,accept-encoding
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior looks like a bug, because modifying the `headers` object inside a hook doesn't affect the real response. I reopened the author's issue on the GitHub: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/6021.

Currently, the only way to add the headers to the response is to use the private `_onConfigureResponse` method of the `RequestHook` class:

```js
class HeadersHook extends RequestHook {
  constructor(requestFilterRules) {
    super(requestFilterRules, { includeBody: false, includeHeaders: true });
  }

  async onRequest () { }

  async onResponse () { }

  _onConfigureResponse (event) {
    super._onConfigureResponse(event);

    event.setHeader('foo', 'bar');
    event.setHeader('bar', 'foo');
  }
}
```

Please note that this API is private and will probably be changed in the future. Please refer to the GitHub issue above to track its status.